# Jcarousel на сайте modx — почему два албома смешиваются?

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://domremonta.pro/ сайт. Внизу есть две карусели(два альбома) - наши документы и отзывы.

Если кликнуть по картинке, то получается что оба альбома объединяются при перелистывании слайдшоу.

Подскажите как исправить?

Comment: Потому что у них одинаковый класс jcarouselREV, у стрелок одинаковые классы, а вы привязали стрелки к пролистыванию слайдера с этим классом.

Comment: значит везде где REV я могу просто переименовать во втором альбоме на что угодно и они не буду смешиватья? вроде бы не получилось, вообще карусель пропала где переименовал - сейчас попробовал

Comment: написал вам ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас одинаковый класс у этих двух слайдеров — `jcarouselREV`. Также у вас одинаковые классы у стрелок, обработка нажатия которых крутит слайдер с классом `jcarouselREV` — это суть проблемы.

Чтобы решить эту проблему, вам надо дать другой класс одному из слайдеров, например, для документов, пусть это будет `jcarouselDOC`. После этого переименуйте стрелки в слайдере документов, пусть это будет `jcarousel-control-prevDOC` и `jcarousel-control-nextDOC`. После этого привязать новые стрелки и инициализировать слайдер вот так:

```
$('.jcarouselDOC').jcarousel();

$('.jcarousel-control-prevDOC').click(function(event) {
    $('.jcarouselDOC').jcarousel('scroll', '-=1');
    event.preventDefault();
});

$('.jcarousel-control-nextDOC').click(function(event) {
    $('.jcarouselDOC').jcarousel('scroll', '+=1');
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Ну и стили не забудьте, достаточно будет влепить их через запятую к имеющимся вот так:

```
.jcarousel-control-prevREV, .jcarousel-control-prevDOC { ... }
.jcarousel-control-nextREV, .jcarousel-control-nextDOC { ... }
```